# R caret's train with poly of a given degree

Tags: r, for-loop, caret, poly

I'm rolling a loop over the degree of the approximating polynomial for training with caret

```
ds = 1:20
for(i in 1:length(ds)){
  print(i)
  d=ds[i]
  fit = train(y~poly(x,degree=d),data=training,method="lm",trControl=fitCtrl)
  # other operations
}
```

running the code gives

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, 0, cols, drop = FALSE) : 
undefined columns selected
```

using d=4 doesn't work, but fixing the degree in the call, i.e. degree=4, works.

Any guess of what's going on here?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
omega = 0.5*pi
xi = 0.5
phi = 0.5*pi
f = function(t)1-exp(-xi*omega*t)*sin(sqrt(1-xi^2)*omega*t+phi)/sin(phi)
sigma = 0.03
train.n = 100
x = seq(0,2*pi,by=2*pi/(train.n-1))
y = f(x)+rnorm(train.n,mean=0,sd=sigma)
training = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
fitCtrl <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV",verboseIter = FALSE)
ds = 1:20
for(i in 1:length(ds)){
  print(i)
  d=4
fit=train(y~poly(x,degree=4),data=training,method="lm",trControl=fitCtrl)
}
```

Comment: edited with a minimal "working" code

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is actually that `caret` is using `all.vars()` on your formula under the hood to create the dataframe needed for modeling. As you can see, `d` is thought to be one of these variables.

```r
all.vars(y~poly(x, degree = d))
#> [1] "y" "x" "d"
```

Typically, one could solve these issues with the use of `I()` in the formula or `force()` around it, but not with `all.vars()`.

The only way to fix this is to not send in `d` in your formula, but have it be a number beforehand.

Using `as.formula(paste0("y ~ poly(x, degree=", d, ")")` in your loop will achieve this (as also suggested by @akrun).

Here is a working example based on your code:

```r
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
omega = 0.5 * pi
xi = 0.5
phi = 0.5 * pi
f = function(t)
  1 - exp(-xi * omega * t) * sin(sqrt(1 - xi ^ 2) * omega * t + phi) / sin(phi)
sigma = 0.03
train.n = 100
x = seq(0, 2 * pi, by = 2 * pi / (train.n - 1))
y = f(x) + rnorm(train.n, mean = 0, sd = sigma)
training = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
fitCtrl <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV", verboseIter = FALSE)

# Shorterning this to 2 to illustrate that it's working
ds = 1:2

for (i in 1:length(ds)) {
  print(i)
  d = ds[i]
  
  fit = train(
    as.formula(paste0("y ~ poly(x, degree=", d, ")")),
    data = training,
    method = "lm",
    trControl = fitCtrl
  )
  
}
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2

# Notice that we have two poly-terms, so it's working
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = dat)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.42507 -0.11917  0.00392  0.13771  0.27425 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)             0.94738    0.01655  57.237  < 2e-16 ***
#> `poly(x, degree = 2)1`  1.10450    0.16552   6.673 1.56e-09 ***
#> `poly(x, degree = 2)2` -1.62076    0.16552  -9.792 3.77e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.1655 on 97 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.5914, Adjusted R-squared:  0.583 
#> F-statistic: 70.21 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We may use `paste` to create the formula here

```
d <- 4
train(as.formula(paste0('y ~ poly(x, degree =', d, ')')), 
      data = training, method = "lm", trControl = fitCtrl)
```

-output

```
Linear Regression 

100 samples
  1 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE        Rsquared   MAE       
  0.03790195  0.9779768  0.02937452
```

---

With the loop, we may need to store the output in a `list`

```
ds <- 1:20
fitlst <- vector('list', length(ds))
for(i in seq_along(ds)){
  print(i)
  d <- ds[i]
  
  fitlst[[i]] <- train(as.formula(paste0('y ~ poly(x, degree =', d, ')')), 
      data = training, method = "lm", trControl = fitCtrl)
      }
```

-output

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 12
[1] 13
[1] 14
[1] 15
[1] 16
[1] 17
[1] 18
[1] 19
[1] 20
> fitlst[[4]]
Linear Regression 

100 samples
  1 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE        Rsquared   MAE       
  0.03790195  0.9779768  0.02937452

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE
```

Comment: how to access now to residuals? fitlst[[1]]$residuals gives NULL now.